# How to use subquery in Append SQL for Access

Tags: ms-access-2007, subquery, sql-insert

I need to add a subquery in my append SQL and it gives me an error:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query.

When I replace the subquery with a constant value, no error is returned.

My code is:

```
INSERT INTO tblActivity ( RequirementReferenceID, ActivityDate, ActivitySource, ActivityTypeID, ActivityDetails, AffectedFieldID )
SELECT [forms]![frmActivity]![UniqueID] AS Expr1, 
Now() AS Expr2, 
[forms]![frmActivity]![ChangedBy] AS Expr3, 
7 AS Expr4, 
(Select RequirementStatus from tblStatus 
where tblStatus.RequirementStatusID = [forms]![frmActivity]![NewRequirementStatus]) AS Expr5, 
48 AS Expr6;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

Instead of nesting a second Select query inside my first Select query I transformed the first one to reflect what I needed from the second.

```
INSERT INTO tblActivity ( RequirementReferenceID, ActivityDate, ActivitySource, ActivityTypeID, ActivityDetails, AffectedFieldID )
SELECT [forms]![frmActivity]![UniqueID], Now(), [forms]![frmActivity]![ChangedBy], 7, RequirementStatus, 48 
from tblStatus 
where tblStatus.RequirementStatusID = [forms]![frmActivity]![NewRequirementStatus];
```

This works perfectly.